# Jquery plugin tablesorter: sorting stops after a question mark has made it to the top row

Tags: jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have this column: D, B, A, ?
On clicking the column header this sorts to: ?,A,B,D. But after that
clicking the column header does nothing. If I replace the question mark with
say Z, it all starts working agian

Answer (score 1):

That is very odd... but, I found that if you set the sorter to "text", it fixes this issue.

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    headers : {
        0: { sorter: "text" }
    } 
});
```

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/rbrjJ/1/). In the numeric column, the "?" is treated like a zero.

Comment: thank you! Now, if I may make use of your knowledge a little more: how do I make the question mark always come out last in the sort order in stead of having it being sorted before 'a'?

Comment: Hmmm, the ascii value of the question mark is less than the ascii value of the alphabet, so I maybe try changing the `?` to a `~` (tilde) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/rbrjJ/2/)) since it's value is after ([ref](http://ascii-table.com/)). And just in case you were interested, I do have a [fork](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/) of the plugin on my github that enables you to [sort text in a numerical column](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers-digits-strings.html) how ever you want.